# .NET JobSchedule Quartz not running

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, quartz-scheduler, taskscheduler

I have got Quartz JobScheduler to run few tasks. It has been working fine but now I have found out it has stopped working on one of the servers.

I use Task Scheduler to trigger the tasks and logs to record the tasks being carried out. But since it has stopped triggering the tasks there are no new logs created.

I am not sure what's gone wrong, I have tried to visit the link to the tasks but it gives me the following error:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

I think the problem seems to be with the web.config but I am not sure I tried to replace the web.config with an older version of the file but it did not help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Account Permissions on the folder.

I added DefaultAppPool and Users in the ACL and it has worked for me.

Hope this helps someone in the future.